# Google cloud bucket verify domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-search-console

My google account has been added to another google cloud platform account. I want to create a simple static website on the cloud, so have been following this: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

I need to create a bucket with the name of the domain. It states you need to be the owner of the domain and you verify with webmaster tools which is fine. I own the domain on the google account I was added with. I have then added the google account email address which I have been added to, but every time I go to create the bucket it still says I need to verify it! Does the domain need to be verified by the prime cloud account? Or is this just a cache thing? Or am I doing something else wrong!?

Comment: I would assume that it's asking you to verify because the identity you are using when attempting to create the bucket is not one of the verified owners of the domain. Also, make sure you are verifying the domain, such as example.com, and not a site on the domain, such as www.example.com.

Comment: ah ok I got confused i thought you could verify you won the domain by verifying you own the site... If I change the cname will that not point he url at google, i don't want to do that until I have moved the site over, I'm a little unclear what i put in the cname also. Currently I'm pointing the domains nameservers at a different vps

Comment: If the domain already has 1+ verified owners, then only they can create the bucket. If the domain has no verified owners, then a verified website owner can create the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I had the site added as https within google search console and static sites hosted in buckets don't support ssl!